# Reading escape characters with XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xml

Hi I have a problem reading escape characters inside an xml using [XMLStreamReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html).

for instance I have this element :

```
<a>foo&amp;bar</a>
```

and when I read the value, everything after the `&amp;` is truncated, and the value I get is "foo"

Any ideas how that could be fixed ?

Comment: Small runnable example with sample input...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is - my test produces the results you expect.

Running

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(
     new StringReader("<tag>foo&amp;bar</tag>"));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
while (reader.hasNext())
{
    reader.next();
    pw.print(reader.getEventType());
    if (reader.hasText())
        pw.append(' ').append(reader.getText());
    pw.println();
}
```

Produces

```
1
4 foo
4 &
4 bar
2
8
```

On JDK 1.6.0.11  - rather old I know. I'll upgrade and post back if results differ.

One thing to bear in mind is that the `XMLStreamReader` can (and does!) break up character data into several blocks, as you see above - the repeated 4 events (4=CHARACTERS) indicates the text of the element is sent as 3 events.

Answer (score 22):

To force XMLStreamReader to return a single string, you have to set the `javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing`  property as indicated by the [XMLStreamReader#next() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#next()):

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);  // decode entities into one string
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
```

Comment: You can use the constant for the property as defined in [XMLInputFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#IS_COALESCING).