# Comparison between woodstox and sjsxp

Tags: java, stax, woodstox

Has anyone used the Stax implementation by Woodstox http://woodstox.codehaus.org and sjsxp https://sjsxp.dev.java.net/. I encountered a wierd issue with sjsxp [XmlStreamReader not reading complete text value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869770/xmlstreamreader-not-reading-complete-text-value) and tried woodstox which resolved my earlier issue.

I wanted to confirm with you guys if anyone has used woodstox before and what was the experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) strongly recommends Woodstox. Faster and less buggy. We support sjsxp, but it is generally a source of mild-to-moderate hair pulling. Our default, validated by lots and lots of users, is Woodstox.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your feedback