# Jdom 1.1.1 - Ampersand problems?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

currently i am debugging and older application for parsing XML Files.

I've noticed, that when I have an element, such as:

```
<value type="String">Hans &amp; Meiser</value>
```

I'd expect in the extraction code (iterating over all elements), when calling

```
Object value = element.getText()
```

that the text results in:

**Hans & Meiser**

but instead of getting the expected result, it seems like that the spaces before and after the ampersand are removed (by jdom)

**Hans&Meiser**

This happens with all entities.

Further, the wrapping of the value within CDATA wasn't successful, too:

```
<value type="String"><![CDATA[Hans & Meiser]]></value>
```

Same issue with CDATA.

Comment: `This happens with all entries` you mean `entities`?

Comment: yes....adjusted the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved, since it is not a jdom issue.
Further analysis leads to the point, that the issue is related to the XMLStreamReader, for which the solution can be found here:

[Reading escape characters with XMLStreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938398/reading-escape-characters-with-xmlstreamreader)